# How to handle web application static resources which browser-cache in kubernetes?

Tags: caching, docker, kubernetes

We are trying to migrate our frontend apps to kubernetes. But when doing a rolling update there is a possibility that the users get 404 due to cacheing with unique sha1 hashes in the URI.

Example:

Simplified directory structure after build #1

```
/index.html
/static/147964a6b54c/app.js
/static/147964a6b54c/style.css
```

Simplified directory structure after build #2

```
/index.html
/static/978b4ccd1dbb/app.js
/static/978b4ccd1dbb/style.css
```

The app uses Cache-Control: public

We have 10 pods running in kubernetes.

We begin rolling update with default update interval of 60 sec.

The problem that can happen now is that the new index.html requests the new URI to app.js (with new hash) but it gets redirected to a container running the old app which does not have that path and therefore throws a 404.

One solution is to only rely on etag header but that makes the clients doing a roundtrip each time and that should not be needed. index.html should use this solution but not the other assets.

I wonder if any other people have run into this situation and found a good solution?

Comment: Is session affinity enabled for ur service? In such cases the request will always end up on the same server from where the session started

Comment: There is a l7 LB in front of the service IP. Service session affinity seems to be based on src IP according to: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/aab6c43a337899fcc200d0a598f5620dc0d817f0/pkg/proxy/iptables/proxier.go#L937 So if i enable affinity all sessions will end up on same pod?

Comment: No. At the time of first request, it will be selected by LB randomly, next time onwards all requests from the user will endup on the same pod.

Comment: How can that be true if you look at the source code? According to iptables man pages --rcheck means: Check if the source address of the packet is currently in the list.